# Improper alignment and Height issue with inline formatting

Tags: sas, sas-ods

```
ods escapechar='^';
%let bmi=^S={font_weight=bold} Body Mass Index(Kg/m^{super 2});
```

When i am trying to create pdf o/p my font is changing in output(Superscript appears in different height) [image: O/P]

Is there any solution for the above issue

Comment: I agree with Joe's answer, but something else you could try is changing `^{super 2}` to `%sysfunc(byte(178))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are overriding the style inline, which SAS handles a bit oddly.  I am assuming this is a `TITLE` element below, but the same rules apply no matter where it's coming from.

```
<td class="c systemtitle">
  <span class="c" style=" font-weight: bold;"> 
      Body Mass Index(Kg/m<sup>2</sup>)
  </span>
</td>
```

Notice the class of the span: it's not a systemtitle anymore, it's just a 'c' (which is generic centered text).  More than likely your style doesn't properly implement superscripts in generic centered text.  I would look at that and see if changing styles works.  In general, it is better to do things like the font-weight:bold in styles rather than in inline formatting; you might find you have better luck with that.

I would also add that in the default style in 9.3 for PDF, this isn't a problem, using the default PDF driver in base SAS.  If you're running this in EG, it uses a slightly different driver to print PDFs, so that could also be worth trying; `options dev=PDF;` fixes it.